# plupload not triggerring FilesAdded event

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, plupload

**First of all, i must appreciate that plupload is a great plugin**. i have used in one of my screens with pluploadQueue(). Now i am trying to use the same plugin in a different screen with custom UI.
This screen has a single link to uploaded and want to upload as and when the file is added.
With the below code, it is not triggering FilesAdded event.

```
var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
  // General settings
  runtimes : 'html5',
  browse_button : 'uploadImage',
  multipart: true,
  multi_selection: false,
  file_data_name: 'uploadFile',
  multipart_params: {uploadName: 'value'},
  url : 'server-url-here',
  // Specify what files to browse for
  filters : {
    max_file_size : '5242880b',
    mime_types: [
      {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"}
    ]
  },
  init: {
    FilesAdded: function(up, files) {
      alert('File added 1');
    }
  }
});
uploader.init();
```

I also tried binding FilesAdded outside of init. but no luck

```
uploader.init();
uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function(up, files) {
  alert('File Added 2');
});
```

Not sure what I am missing.

JFYI: The file I am trying to upload is a jpg image with less than 1MB size.

Comment: Start by removing the `filters` option and see if it makes a difference. If not, you may provide a jsfiddle

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I was into other things.I removed filters option but no luck. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R85mh/1/)

Comment: I encounter no problem (after adding pluploadfull as external ressource) on FF26, Chr31, IE11  and a 70kB jpeg image http://jsfiddle.net/R85mh/2/

Comment: Thanks for your time, jbl. Here is an update. I checked and i already have these scripts imported into my web page (as I told in my question, there is a working plupload in another screen). I forgot to save jsfiddle after adding them. I have updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R85mh/3/) and it works now. I tested the same with my application and it works fine with Chrome, Firefox. But still, not working with IE. I am using IE 11 too. And surprise is, it does not report any errors in IE. Don't know what is wrong.

Comment: OK. Here is an easy step of replication. In plupload examples, just add an alert statement to FilesAdded event in "custom.html" example. You can see chrome (32) working well with that and IE(11) suffering.

Comment: might be that the plupload version does not contain latest fixes for IE11, see  https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/issues/906 and http://plupload.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=4083

Comment: Thank you very much jbl. You saved my time. It started working after I took the latest version. **+1**

Comment: Nice! Then you should post an answer to your own question and mark it as accepted. It will help people encountering the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue exists with the plupload version that I was using i.e. plupload-2.0.0. Taken plupload-master and it works well now.